# IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [beans1.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am getting above exception when i try to run simple spring example

Following line of code try to read spring beans from beans1.xml

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans1.xml");
```

Following is the complete exception i am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [beans1.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans1.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I have put xml file in every possible location hoping that program will detect the file. But still this program can not find this bean configuration file. Also i am using maven as the build tool, but i am running the program using Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put it in `resources` directory of maven project

```
src/main/resources/beans1.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

check the name,your bean.xml file name should be same as what you have mentioned here ie., beans.xml  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans1.xml"):